# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED error android

Tags: android, android-manifest

I get the INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED error when trying to deploy my updated app on my phone. (can't quite recall everything I changed I must admit)
Here is the logcat:

```
    11-19 01:17:34.709 344-344/? E/installd: Couldn't opendir/data/app/vmdl535902261.tmp: No such file or directory
    11-19 01:17:34.710 19506-19506/? E/Pm: Failure details:Bundle[{android.content.pm.extra.STATUS=4,android.content.pm.extra.PACKAGE_NAME=ProjectRomero.CarRemote, android.content.pm.extra.SESSION_ID=535902261, android.content.pm.extra.LEGACY_STATUS=-108, android.content.pm.extra.STATUS_MESSAGE=INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl535902261.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #28): <activity> does not have valid android:name}]
```

and my AndroidManifest:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="ProjectRomero.CarRemote">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

        <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
            android:required="true" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

            <activity
                android:name=".scan_activity"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <activity
                android:name=".remote_activity"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            </activity>

        </application>
    </manifest>
```

And my two activities headers:

```java
  package ProjectRomero.CarRemote;
  //imports
  public class remote_activity extends AppCompatActivity {}



  package ProjectRomero.CarRemote;
  //imports
  public class scan_activity extends AppCompatActivity {}
```

I must admit I am quite confused, how can I correct this error? tried cleaning quite a few times, even recreated a project and copied the code, deleted the previous version of the app on my phone, restarted my phone, and still nothing...

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change package="ProjectRomero.CarRemote"
to package="projectromero.carremote" in the manifest

For some reason the Caps put it off

Comment: Thanks! thats what i finally did, created a new projet, didn't use caps and copy pasted all the code